# List of Dataframes as input to Keras

Tags: python, list, keras

I am new to Keras and i am stuck with this problem. My input dataset is not only one Pandas Dataframe but a list. I try to implement with Dense and i am receiving this error :

```
When checking model input: the list of numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s) but instead got the following list of 546 arrays: ......
```

Is Keras capable of receiving as an input a list of matrices?

Answer (score 1):

If each of your dataframes are independent (in terms of data they have) you can concatenate them into 1 dataframe and pass that 1 dataframe as input.

Another approach: if each dataframe is actually 1 input, you can flatten that input and pass it as 1 input.

3rd option, we do this with images where we have 3 dimensional input matrix to keras and it works well.

4th option is an improvement on 3rd option which is having N dimensional input.

5th option for time series dataset. Pass each dataframe as  sequence of inputs and train a LSTM based network for capturing time series trends.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Each column of the dataframe is a whole time-series from one specific area. So each dataframe is one sample from a lot of areas. The dataframes is independent from each other. I think the 2nd option may work if i flatten the dataframes (column-major) and maybe in the end of the array i will add a label so i will do binary classification. So instead of a list of matrices(Dataframes) i will have a list of arrays(lists).

Comment: Cool, flatten it out but then the weights learner won't be proper for each feature in the time series. I would have gone for an LSTM based time series network.

Comment: hmm maybe it's better to flatten and then make one single matrix with rows ( each of the flatten arrays) and i will leave the last column as the label ( output)

Comment: That will work but say for feature F1 at time t1 weight on layer 1 will be w1. For the same feature F1 (now it's flattened, so its I'd will be higher) say f21 at time t2 the weight at layer 1 will be different w21. So learning of features won't be good. But your call. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I created a list of lists as i said but still get the same error. Also my Dataframes don't have the same amount of elements (same columns but different rows ) so i cannot create an one single matrix cause there are gonne be some empty cells

Comment: Even if the list worked i would still have problem with the input_shape , as my arrays don't have the same length

Comment: You need to pad your input sequence, also try and share some code so I can have a look at it and guide you better.

Comment: Hey man, i converted my lists of arrays to np.array(list) and pad them with zeros and it worked. Not good results though, but worked!

Comment: Cool. Started working, now you can improve it. All the best :)